# Differentiability and integrability of a function composed with itself

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, riemann-integration

I am reviewing for an exam and came across a multi-part question that I am having a hard time with. We are asked to prove or disprove the following statements. If a statement is false, what additional hypothesis would make it true? (Note: $f^{\circ 2}=f\circ f$).

Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$ be a continuous function.

1. If $f$ is differentiable, then so is $f^{\circ 2}$.
2. If $f^{\circ 2}$ is differentiable, then so is $f$.

Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$ be a function (not necessarily continuous).

3. If $f$ is Riemann integrable, then so is $f^{\circ 2}$.
4. If $f^{\circ 2}$ is Riemann integrable, then so is $f$.

I think statement 1 is as simple as saying that if $f$ is differentiable, then $f^{\circ 2}$ is the composition of differentiable functions and is thus differentiable. Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Comment: I am not familiar with the notation $f^{o2}$. What does it mean?

Comment: Nice first queston, BTW. We should frame it and hang it on the 'fridge.

Comment: Given a function $f:X\rightarrow X$, the function  $f^{\circ 2}(x)=f(f(x))$. Does that clarify it?

Comment: Yep, thanks very much.

Comment: I agree with your assesment of statement 1. For statement 2, how would we express the derivative of $f^{o2}$ without needing to write $f'(x)$?

Comment: My thought was to write it in terms of the definition of the derivative:  $f^{\circ 2'}(x_0)=\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} \frac{f^{\circ 2}(x)-f^{\circ 2}(x_0)}{x}$.

Comment: Expand that out, perhaps.